# Angular JS, json method called from outside of controller

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i have this code, which gets a json, inside a controller
i need to know how am i able to call inner method, from outside controller.

```
var app;
(function (){
app = angular.module("gallery", []);

app.controller("galleryController", ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){
    var gallery = this;
    gallery.data = [];

    gallery.getJson = function(){
        $http.get('/urltojson/main-hero.json').success(function(data){
            gallery.data = data;
        });
    }

    this.getJson();
}]);  })();
```

is it possible to call getJson from outside the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `angular.element` and get the `scope()` of the element that resides within the controller you want to call methods on.

Example:

```
<div ng-controller="galleryController"><span id="test"></span></div>
```

You can do:

```
var scope = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#test' ) ).scope();
scope.getJson();
```

Comment: var a = angular.element("#gallery").scope() that doesn´t return getJson method, dunno why. html is <ul ng-controller="galleryController as gallery" id="gallery">
    <img ng-src="{{gallery.data.imgUrl}}">
    <p>{{gallery.data.lowertext}}</p>
</ul>

Comment: ok, got how to call the json method, but the two way data binding somehow is not working, the process for this is, i have a json, which is loaded when page loads, i have the hability to change json without refreshing page, problem is that when i refresh json, this happens for ex <p>{{gallery.data.lowertext}}</p>